# SSL configuration for DigitalOcean docker image deployed using GitHub actions

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, github-actions, digital-ocean

The app that I have deployed into DigitalOcean (DO) droplet by using the docker container registry. The issue that I have now of integrating the let's encrypt certificate (SSL) for that docker image. I don't have any experience on this but I tried some tutorials like this [SSL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose). However, i can't get the https:// for my domain and sub domain. https://dev.example.com

Folder structure of my app as below: ( added only important paths )

```
root
+--.github/workflows
    -- main.yml
+-- app
    -- .next
    -- node_modules
    -- public
    -- src
    -- Dockerfile
+-- nginx-conf
    -- nginx.conf
+-- server
    -- node_modules
    -- src
    -- Dockerfile
```

nginx-conf is the one that i added to set SSL using reverse proxy. that file include this server block.

```
server {
        listen 8000 default_server;
        listen [::]:8000 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com dev.example.com;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri /index.tsx;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://server/api/;
        }
}
```

app/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=test
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

server/Dockerfile

```
# Create build
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /server
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
RUN npm i -g typescript ts-node
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Run Build
FROM node:alpine as prod
WORKDIR /server

COPY --from=build /server/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /server/build ./
RUN npm ci --only=production
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

main.yml file build server and client apps by SSH into DO droplet. Finally deploy to the container. ( only include sample code )

```
jobs:
  buildClient:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: app
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build client docker image
        run: |
          docker login -u ${{ secrets }} -p ${{ secrets }} registry.digitalocean.com
          docker build -t registry.digitalocean.com/....... .
          docker push registry.digitalocean.com/..........

deployContainers:
    name: Deploy containers to DO Droplet
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [
      buildClient,
      buildServer
      ]
    steps:
      - name: SSH into Droplet
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.4
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets }}
          username: ${{ secrets }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets }}
          script: |
            docker login -u ${{ secrets }} -p ${{ secrets }} 
            registry.digitalocean.com
            docker stop app
            docker rm app
            docker image rm registry.digitalocean.com/.......

            docker pull registry.digitalocean.com/..........
            docker run --name app -p 80:3000 -d registry.digitalocean.com/.........
```

Comment: you need to have nginx use your certs

Comment: Hi @AsadAwadia can you pls elaborate your suggestion ?